# CGRectZero and sizeToFit

Tags: iphone, uiview

I see code that looks something like this sometimes:

```
NSArray *segmentedControl = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *ctrl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentedControl];
    ctrl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    ctrl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    ctrl.frame = CGRectZero;
    [ctrl sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = ctrl;
    [ctrl release];
```

For the CGRectZero and sizeToFit, why is this done?  Is it the fact that you want the object to at the 0, 0 origin, and then by making the frame width and height to 0, but calling sizeToFit, it fills up the view?  Looking at the UIView documentation, I'm not really sure what "Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews" means.  Thanks.

Comment: sizeToFit confuses me too.  I primarily use it for constructing toolbars, I use it to make sure my toolbar is the default height, then I set the origin and width manually

Answer (score 2):

In a UIView `sizeToFit` calls `sizeThatFits:` with the view's current size.

The default implementation of `sizeThatFits:` returns the current value of the view, in other words it does pretty much nothing in most cases (some subclasses of UIView override this method so it returns something more useful, ex: UILabel)

In other words `sizeThatFits` it is a "Template Method", a method that is made for extending the functionality of the class. It's main purpose is to be overridden.